# how to upload file large then 100M with tornado

Tags: python, tornado

i want to upload a file large then 100M, but i got an error.

i found the official [document 4.0](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/releases/v4.0.0.html) mention about large file problem,but i didn't find the example.

how to solve this problem. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass HTTP options to `app.listen`:

```
app.listen(8888, max_body_size=200 * 1024 * 1024)
```

Any of the [HTTP1ConnectionParameters](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/http1connection.html#tornado.http1connection.HTTP1ConnectionParameters) can be passed as keyword arguments to `listen` this way.

Comment: thank you ,it work to me. the document say """By default uploaded files are fully buffered in memory; if you need to handle 
files that are too large to comfortable keep in memory see the stream_request_body class decorator. """   is this a good function,i want to try.

Comment: Yes, stream_request_body is a good function, you should try it. =)